# MYSQL schema design for people with multiple user names without userids

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for advice on how to best setup my db tables.  I'm tracking user stats that are contained in a json request. Unfortunately the JSON only contains a username, no userid.  I have no idea that a user has changed their name on the remote service unless they tell me.  When they do tell me, I can combine their scores by associating their multiple names into a single username.  I do this by assigning a aliasID field to the value of the new userid   This is a simplified version of how I'm handling it now.

**tblUsers**

```
userid   username  alias
........................
1        john      4
2        mary      0
3        john2     4
4        john3     4
```

**tlbStats**

```
userid   score 
...............
1        10
1        100
3        50
4        150
```

My sql query to get a combined score for all of users which will combine all usernames with the same alias is:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN tblUsers.alias = 0 THEN tblUser.userid ELSE tblUser.alias END AS mainID,
tblUser.username, sum(tblStats.score) as totScore

FROM tblUsers INNER JOIN tblStats on tblUsers.userid = tblStats.userid

GROUP BY mainID
```

My current way of doing it works.  But I assume there's a better way.  Handling username changes is a longer process than it needs to be.  I have to manually reset all the alias ids to the new userid.

Comment: I think you may consider moving the username into another table with the createdAt field it would help you lot

Comment: Is this a database design question or is querying your existing database structure question? Not sure what you can improve on in the absence of a proper, unique user id

Comment: db design.  What can I be doing better, if anything, given my circumstances?

Comment: VMM - Can you explain why that would help?  Thank you.